# Apex code formatter in Eclipse (Force.com IDE plugin)

Tags: apex, eclipse

I am searching for Apex code formatter in Eclipse (Force.com IDE plugin for Eclipse). I would like to have something similar to Java formatter (CTRL+SHIFT+F). Is that possible?

Comment: I've been meaning to write my own, but hopefully there's one already out there!

Comment: Copy the code into a Java editor and press CTRL+SHIFT+F. Then copy it back into the APEX editor. Unfortunately, that is not solution, just a nasty workaround.

Comment: That's why some people like to use Sublime Text 3[http://www.sublimetext.com/3]. It's a favorite tool among people inside of SF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it's not possible yet. It's not currently supported with Force.com IDE, BUT you can vote on that idea at ideaExchange

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006rPZAAY