# Apex code formatter in Eclipse plugin

Tags: apex, eclipse

I have gone through this link  [Apex code formatter in Eclipse (Force.com IDE plugin)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22038/apex-code-formatter-in-eclipse-force-com-ide-plugin][1]) which was posted before a year. Is there any new plugin for beautifying the code?

Answer (score 2):

As well as voting up the idea you link to, you could comment and engage here [Auto formatting code](https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/issues/123) which is in the open source project where Force.com IDE contributions can be made.

A block to anyone taking on the formatting job is that (at least the last time I looked) the Apex parser (that also has to be able to parse SOQL) had not been opened sourced. That (or a clear and unchanging API to it) would be needed to write a good formatter. The other requirement is someone having the right skills and a few weeks available to do the work...

**PS**

This paid for IDE [Illuminated Cloud](http://www.illuminatedcloud.com/) looks like it has a [flexible code formatter](http://www.illuminatedcloud.com/home/formatter) built in and perhaps other [Community Contributed Tools](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Tools) do as well.